# Git: Merge old repository into a branch of an existing repository (while keeping commit history)

Tags: git

I have a repository called `website-old`, which is the old version of my website (from 2 years ago). It only has 1 branch called **`main`**

I also have a repository called `website`, which is the current, live version of my website. It also has only 1 branch called **`main`**

I would like to move everything from `website-old`/**`main`** to `website`/**`outdated`**

I intend to preserve previous commits & file history.

Comment: Branches should remain separate, right? So there is no "merging"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two projects in a single repository with unrelated branches, you only need to fetch:

```
cd website
git fetch path/to/website-old main:outdated
```

This will fetch the `main` branch of website-old and store it as `outdated` in your current repository.

Comment: bash:~/Documents/website-old$ git fetch ../website-old main:outdated

returns `fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/outdated of non-bare repository`

Comment: @haste you state in your question "it only has 1 branch called main". According to that error message, it must also have a branch named `outdated` and that branch is currently checked out. You cannot fetch into a checked out branch.

Comment: @haste note that in your error message, your working directory is `website-old` and not `website`. You are not fetching from a different repository, you are fetching from the same repository to itself.